# String variable is not accepting "?" sign

Tags: javascript, string, variables, protractor, sign

I made code with:

```
element(by.className('charge')).getText()
    .then(function(text){
        var blabla = "Is this my string?";

        expect(text.match(blabla)).toBe(true);
        console.log(text);
    });
```

And even is output of my console equal to my blabla variable,
I'm getting result:

> Expected [ 'Is this my string' ] to be true.

without any "?" sign.

How is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The argument for `match` is:

> A regular expression object. If a non-RegExp object obj is passed, it is implicitly converted to a RegExp by using new RegExp(obj).

So don't pass it a string. Explicitly pass it a regular expression object (since that involves much less pain that converting strings in to regex and having to deal with two levels of syntax to escape through).

Regular expressions treat `?` as a special character (in the context of your code it means "The `g` should appear 0 or 1 time". You need to escape question marks if you want to match them.

```
var blabla = /Is this my string\?/;
```

That said, if you want to match the whole string, it would be easier to just make that the test:

```
var blabla = "Is this my string?";
expect(text).toBe(blabla);
```

Answer (score 3):

The argument to `match` is meant to be a *regular expression* where `?` has a special meaning. You probably meant `toEqual()` instead:

```
expect(element(by.className('charge')).getText()).toEqual("Is this my string?");
```

If you want a regular expression match, make a regular expression object and use `toMatch()`:

```
var blabla = /Is this my string\?/;
expect(element(by.className('charge')).getText()).toMatch(blabla);
```

Note that in protractor `expect()` is "patched" to resolve promises implicitly and you don't need to use `then()`.

Comment: @Yte please accept Quentin's answer as it is more detailed than mine. Glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

You probably misundertood what `match` method does in JS strings:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

It will basically use the regex to return the groups that match, so, in this case

```
< ("Is this my string").match("Is this my string?");
> ["Is this my string"]
```

The answer is correct. What you want to do is simply compare the strings, just do:

```
< "Is this my string" === "Is this my string?";
> false
```

Note it has nothing to do with the test engine you are using (that I do not know), **but** there propably is a better way to do it than

```
expect(text === blabla).toBe(true);
```

Something

```
expect(text, blabla).toBeEqual();
```

So the error message is pretty ;)

Answer (score 0):

The string argument provided to `match()` is a regular expression and the `?` in this context means "match the previous zero or one times". Which it does in your example :-)

You can explicitly escape the question make by writing `\?`, in which case the behavior will be as you expect.

Cheers,